# SOQL: How to get the biggest value from a field and compare to a another on query?

Tags: soql, sql, database

I need to get the biggest value from field createddate and then compare this value to another date on a query/soql.

I think about using "order by createddate desc limit 1" but I don't know how to compare to another date in the same query

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the specific queries you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

SOQL, even though looks similar to traditional RDBMS SQL, it lacks many capabilities. Using fields on both of side expressions is one such feature SOQL doesn't support.

For ex., you cannot do this `select id from account where billingstreet != shippingstreet`.

To do what you are looking for, you need to issue first query, get data and use that value in second query.  For ex.,

```
Account act = [select createddate from account order by createddate desc limit 1];
List<Account> latestAccounts = [select id, name from account where createddate = :act.createddate]
```